# Use interactive python in pythonbrew

Tags: python, pythonbrew

I installed `pythonbrew` and then switch to python3.2.

```
$pythonbrew install 3.2 
$pythonbrew switch 3.2
```

Then I found I couldn't run python interactively:

```
$python
Usage: /home/raincole/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.2/bin/python [--prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--help|--abiflags]
```

Am I really using python 3.2? I can't even run `python --version` to see what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Silly me, I didn't know that Python 3 interpreters run as a program named `python3`. Type `python3` at the command line and you should be fine.